# URL to facebook post within ifram returns "Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, clickjacking

if i open the following link in **iframe**, it works fine.
http://www.facebook.com/{pageID}?sk=**messages_inbox**&action=read&tid=%7BmessageID%7D

however, if i open the following in iframe, 
http://www.facebook.com/{pageID}/**posts**/{postID}
it shows **“Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options”**.

What would be the workaround to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a public facing page, i.e, no login required, you can route the request through a proxy on your server, removing the X-Frame-Options header from the response.

Answer (score 0):

I've just resolved this issue by fixing the Page Tab options.

Not having the Page Tab set right, oddly enough yielded the X-frame error.